# Ghostscript.NET 1.2.3 'Method not found' running as a Function App

Tags: c#, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

I am not sure why this is failing at `var img = rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, 1);` with the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Drawing.Image Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer.GetPage(Int32, Int32)'

My path to the dll is correct and the 64-bit version. The GhostScript Rasterizer can open the memory stream and then fails on `GetPage()`. It bombs out the debugger without hitting a breakpoint if I have that line uncommented.

Here is the code:

```
            var dpi = 90;
            GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), workingDirectory + @"\gsdll64.dll", string.Empty, GhostscriptLicense.GPL);

            using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
            {
                rasterizer.Open(ms, gvi, false);

                if (rasterizer.PageCount > 0)
                {
                    var img = rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **GetPage** method only works accepting 3 arguments, as you can verify on the following link:

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer/GhostscriptRasterizer/GetPage/php-ghostscriptrasterizer-getpage-method-examples.html

Please, check if using all the arguments works for you, as this could be the cause of the "Method not found" error.